# Organize photos into albums using API

Tags: google-photos

The new [Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums#Album) seems to allow the creation of albums and uploading images to albums, but I'd like to organize existing photos in Google Photos into new albums; is this currently possible somehow?